# How did 're' + 'torquere' semantically shift to mean retort an argument or accusation?

Tags: etymology

1. p 1811 on [*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.ca/Oxford-Latin-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0199580316) doesn't expound the semantic shift from 1 to 3b below. I read [Etymology on "retort"](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=retort).
2. I don't wrestle or fight, and don't understand Definition 1. Who's wrenching what/who? What's being twisted "round so as to face the opposite direction"?

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Retorquere means literally "to wrench or twist back" so in wrestling terms it would mean something along the lines of pulling ones limbs back like getting someone in a leg or arm bar.

The "link" to retort comes in the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th senses, meaning a turning back. A retort is a "comeback" it's turning the argument back on itself. Though it likely originally meant something along the lines of "using one's argument against them" it has come to mean a response or rebuttal in general over time.

I've found many Latin words come into English in a more figurative sense than literal. It's kind of like having to read between the lines.